# Droppable Re-enable - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vMQVy/2/

Take the item, put to the trash.... Then remove that item from trash and try again put there again (same or other item) ...

Droppable still "disabled"

Part of code:

```
$(function() {
        $(".item").draggable({
                revert: 'invalid',
                cursor: 'move'

        });

        $("#items").droppable({
                drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    $("#trash").droppable( "enabled" )
                }
        });

        $("#trash").droppable({
                out: function() {
                    $(this).droppable( "enabled" )   
                },
                drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    $(this).droppable( "disable" )
                }
        });
});
```

Could help me with a solution?

Comment: It's because you are not re-enabling it. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried as per jqueryui's documentation:

```
//setter
$( this ).droppable( "option", "disabled", true );
$( this ).droppable( "option", "disabled", false );
```